# Matching contents of an html file with keyword python

Tags: python, html, compare, match

I am making a download manager. And I want to make the download manager check the md5 hash of an url after downloading the file. The hash is found on the page. It needs to compute the md5 of the file ( this is done), search for a match on the html page and then compare the WHOLE contents of the html page for a match.

my question is how do i make python return the whole contents of the html and find a match for my "md5 string"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import urllib` and use `urllib.urlopen` for getting the contents of an html. `import re` to search for the hash code using regex. You could also use `find` method on the string instead of regex.

If you encounter problems, then you can ask more specific questions. Your question is too general.

Answer (score 3):

[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) lib is what you want to use. Will save you lots of trouble